# SetLocation(int , int) is not working

Tags: java, swing

Why `setLocation(int, int)` is not able to set the position of the button. I have the class `ABC` which add two `JButton` to the `JPanel` and then add this panel to the `JFrame` but while setting the position of the JButton the buttons are adding side by side but not at the desired location. I think it is happening because of `Flowloyout`.

```
ABC(){
    jframe = new JFrame();
    jframe.setSize(600, 600);
    jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    jframe.setVisible(true);
    start = true;
    jbutton1 = new JButton("Button1");
    jbutton2 = new JButton("Button2");


    jbutton1.setLocation(200, 500);
    jbutton2.setLocation(300, 550);

    // first window of the application
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    jp.add(jbutton1);
    jp.add(jbutton2);

    jframe.add(jp);
    }
```

Comment: As per [these similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+swing+setLocation+not+working+site:stackoverflow.com), you're ignoring the layout managers.  Better not to use `setLocation(...)` but instead to read the layout manager tutorials, learn to use them, and then use them in this and future programs.

Comment: BTW - was the idea to have two buttons in a single row, centered at the bottom of the GUI? (A typo. would have dropped one button lower, only partly visible above the bottom edge.) If so, that effect can easily be achieved by using two panels. One panel to center the buttons, itself added to the 'page end' of another panel.